# Multi-colored axis in Chart Director

Tags: chart-director

I am replacing an old charting package with chart director.  The previous package produced multiply colored axis, so that you can quickly see where different days begin/end, like this:

[image]

Does chart-director support anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to add thick custom lines using BaseChart.addLine, or thin custom rectangles using BaseChart.addText (create an empty text box, use Box.setSize to set its size and Box.setBackground to set the background and border colors). Basically, you would need to determine the standing and ending positions of each day, and then add a think or a thin box just below the x-axis.

Comment: Sounds like this would work, but would require a lot of fiddling around!  Not sure my client would be willing to pay for how long it would need. How do I determine positions of each day?  Is there a call to chart director that will give me this?